# How to get the incremented value in a column based on the other column in sql

Tags: sql-server

I have the below table records. For Every TranNo I have to increment one in the expected result column. Is it possible?

[image]

How to get this result in sqlserver?

I am unable to get the appropriate result

```
 <Expected Result>
1
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

I tried:

```
SELECT BatchNo,
       TranNo,
       WorkSource
FROM table1 WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE BatchNo IN ('0000000420', '0000000421', '0000000422')
  AND PROCESSDATE = '20190206'
GROUP BY WorkSource,
         BATCHNO,
         TranNo;
```

Comment: Why is the first row in there twice? Is it possible to "jump" over tranNos? (I.e. can we see Batch 001, TranNo 1, followed by Batch 001, TranNo 3, without ever seeing TranNo 2?)

Comment: What attempts have you made?

Comment: Comments aren't the right place for attempts, you should [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54571598/edit) your question.

Comment: Why `WITH (NOLOCK)` out of interest as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this

```
create table #temp (WorkSource char(3), BatchNo char(3), TranNo int)
insert into #temp values
('012', '001', 1),
('012', '001', 1),
('012', '001', 2),
('012', '001', 3),
('012', '002', 1),
('012', '002', 2),
('012', '003', 3),
('013', '005', 1),
('013', '005', 2)

SELECT *, Dense_Rank() OVER(ORDER BY BatchNo, TranNo) AS Row_Number  
FROM #temp
```

Comment: I think this is what he's intending to do. The "intended result" above doesn't make sense. It's just a distinct count of TranNo, where a count of TranNo per batch would make more sense.

Comment: It returns 87 records, but actually it should return 32 records only as per my requirement.

Comment: That would be how I'd interpret what is needed, so I think we need more test data + expected results and explanation - what would the 32 records be?

Comment: No. I am still getting 87 records only after the #temp table script. I am expecting the expected result column in the same #temp table.

Comment: @Mohamedasiq Please check the demo link https://rextester.com/IXOP42884. It may be some other issue.

Comment: For every TranNo Expected result column should be incremented by 1.

Comment: @Mohamedasiq for this you need to change the requirement and you can also check with only OVER(ORDER BY TranNo).

Answer (score 4):

Try with this:

```
;WITH LagTranNo AS
(
    SELECT 
        *, 
        IsDiffTranNo = CASE WHEN TranNo =  LAG(TranNo) OVER (ORDER BY WorkSource, BatchNo, TranNo) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    FROM 
        YourTable
)
SELECT
    L.*,
    SUM(L.IsDiffTranNo) OVER (ORDER BY WorkSource, BatchNo, TranNo)
FROM
    LagTranNo AS L
```

I believe you want to add 1 only when the `TranNo` changes. Need to be careful with the ordering.

**Note**: `LAG` with only work with SQL Server 2012+.